# Have already set PYTHONPATH, but why it cant able to import my custom modules in Python?

Tags: python, python-import, environment, pythonpath

The following is my 'env' in my mac via Terminal
[image]

And I have already add my workspace path with PYTHONPATH in file ~/.bash_profile like below:

Since I want to import some custom functions which written by myself, here is the custom function bath:
/Users/LSH/WSFG_DEV/workspace/ws_functions (But I think it's better to include the whole workspace)
[image]

So weird that although it says no module named 'ws_functions', but the VSC still can address my custom functions (etc: send_IFTTT_notice_rich / send_IFTTT_notice_simple...)

[image]

May I know what kind of things I am still missing?

**Update @ 25 July :**
So weird that I cant even print the PYTHONPATH with os module...
[image]

Comment: can you print the `PYTHONPATH` ? `import os print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])`. This will ensure that paths are okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not running in a bash login shell, so `~/.bash_profile` doesn't do anything. In fact, you're not even using bash, so `~/.bash_profile` doesn't do anything. Try setting `PYTHONPATH` in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Yes. Once I set the PYTHONPATH in ~/.zshrc I got back everything now. Thanks hobbs :)